# Zlib in Xcode using objective c

Tags: objective-c, osx-lion

I am using [this link](http://www.clintharris.net/2009/how-to-gzip-data-in-memory-using-objective-c/)
as my CDTest.h and CDTest.m and in my TestAppDelegate.m i am calling these class with button action as

```
-(IBAction)Zipbtn:(id)sender{

    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSLog(@"paths=%@",paths);
    NSString* dPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"dpaths=%@",dPath);

    NSString* txtfile = [dPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.txt"];
    NSLog(@"txtfile=%@",txtfile);

    NSData* data=[txtfile dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"data=%@",data);

   CDTest *obj=[[CDTest alloc]init];
    [obj gzipData:data];


}
```

but showing

> warning instance method -gzipData not found also on button click shows :-[CDTest gzipData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8d7a009070
>   Please help me out as i am new to Mac osx.

Comment: Did you change the name of the class from `LFCGzipUtility`?

Comment: Yes! i have change classname to CDTest

Comment: Please show us the new source files; the mistake is almost certainly there.

Comment: i have also included libz.1.2.5.dylib in my application but i dono where i am making mistake.

Comment: http://www.clintharris.net/2009/how-to-gzip-data-in-memory-using-objective-c/ same example i have used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is a class method - not an instance method. You should be using:

```
[CDTest gzipData:data]
```

Additionally, you're actually creating an NSData from the string when you do:

```
NSData* data=[txtfile dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

What you want to do is get the data from the content of the file, which is:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:txtfile];
```

Comment: Audio and video files are not working with the above examples,can somebody help me or give me proper link.

Comment: for the first thing, you're creating NSData from the string, not from the contents of the file - I'll update the answer